# jacoco report generaration from exec file

Tags: jacoco

hello I have a jacoco exec file(run time agent) generated from my application build done through jenkins which is on different machine.I am trying to import and view report using eclipse in my local machine.But is shows coverage as zero even though there is content in excec file.Any idea why and a resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely because local class files in Eclipse are not the same as the ones that were used during creation of exec file. See http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/classids.html

Resolution is to have exact same classes during generation of report as during execution, e.g. by generating report directly in Jenkins.

Comment: thanks solved the issue by giving  the class files of the jar in eclipse instead of source code and it solved the issue